# Can SiteMinder add HTTP response headers for the browser?

Tags: siteminder

I know SiteMinder can add HTTP headers to the HTTP *request* so that backend devices (the web server, app server, etc) can have the headers for processing.  But on the way out back to the client (browser), can SiteMinder add a HTTP *Response* Header so the client can use it?

I see a response type of WebAgent-HTTP-Header-Variable but it seems that is only accessible on the server side.

I've quick searched through some documentation and Googled, but the SiteMinder documentation is well, less than I would hope for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my recent understanding, HTTP Headers are only accessible at the server and never available on the client side unless the IIS/Web server/Application pushes them through.

Here is a link to CA's SiteMinder information that does NOT specify the above specifically:
https://wiki.ca.com/display/sm1252sp1/Default+HTTP+Headers+Used+by+the+Product
but it does say it passes it to the 'web application', which to me means only to the server.

So if you need the variable, you have to capture it at the server and send it to the client browser. In most cases this should NOT be done.  Ask you company's security group for guidance here on SiteMinder headers.   The company I work for created custom headers for my app, not the ones automatically sent from a canned SiteMinder installation.